# Confusion in Var args parameter while passing no-argument

Tags: java, arguments, variadic-functions

Why sifter(C[]... c2) is called while calling only sifter() with no argument. I think here should be ambiguity in methods but the code is compiling and giving the output as `-41`.

```
package abc;

class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

public class ComingThru {
    static String s = "-";
    public static void main(String...a) {
        A[] aa = new A[2];
        B[] ba = new B[2];
        sifter();
        sifter(aa,ba);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static void sifter(A[]... a2) {
        s += "1";
    }

    static void sifter(C[]... c2) {
        s += "4";
    }

    static void sifter(B[]... b1) {
        s += "2";
    }   
}
```

Comment: `14: invokestatic  #29                 // Method sifter:([[LC;)V`  this is the byte code for line sifter(); and from there we can figure out it is converting method `sifter()` to `sifter(C[]... c2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing the Java Language Specification

[Section 15.12.2.4. Phase 3: Identify Applicable Variable Arity Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4), it states towards the end that:

> If no applicable variable arity method is found, a compile-time error
>   occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the most specific method (§15.12.2.5) is chosen among the
>   applicable variable-arity methods.

Now looking at section 15.12.2.5 right below in the same page, it states:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

Therefore, it shows that all of the 3 method declarations are applicable for the `sifter();` call. However, `static void sifter(C[]... c2)` is the **most specific** since you can call the other two methods (A[]... and B[]...) with the same input and there would be no compilation error.

Comment: I have added another method `static void sifter(Integer[]... i)`, Now it is showing compile error, so why sifter is checking for specific arguments though it is accepting no arguments.

Comment: @hemkaran_raghav 

`static void sifter(Integer[]... i)` is its own maximally specific method. So now there are 2 maximally specific methods Integer[]... and C[]... -- At compile time, which method one to choose is ambiguous as both of them apply and both of them are maximally specific. Therefore, it raises a compilation error. (Reference section 15.12.2.5)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to the hierarchy Level, It is calling that method whose parameter is the lowest in order of Inheritance. You can take a example, if we replace `B` with `C` then it will the method with `B[]...b1` as argument.

```
    package abc;

    class A {}
    class C extends A {}
    class B extends C {}

    public class ComingThru {
        static String s = "-";
        public static void main(String...a) {
            A[] aa = new A[2];
            B[] ba = new B[2];
            sifter();
            sifter(aa,ba);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        static void sifter(A[]... a2) {
            s += "1";
        }

        static void sifter(C[]... c2) {
            s += "4";
        }

        static void sifter(B[]... b1) {
            s += "2";
        }   
    }
```

Now the output will be `-21`

Comment: Yes, this will be the output. But what is the reason behind it?

Comment: Lowest in the hierarchy level. If we add another method accepting Object as varagrs, still it will call method with B.

Comment: Yes, your correct but why is that. If we look at the method prototype sifter() there is no method defined for such prototype.